# How to set packagingOptions dynamically in Android build.gradle for specific build type

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I want to set the `useLegacyPackaging` packagingOptions for a specific build to reduce the apk size without success.  The option works, but it always applies to all build types.  It's something like this in my `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst '**/*.so'
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      some properties here
    }
    staging {
      some properties here
    }
    release {
      some properties here
      packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
          useLegacyPackaging true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the example, I added `useLagacyPackaging` options to release build type.  I expect it to only impact the release build, but in reality it is impacting the other build types as well.  The apk file size for all builds got reduced equally.

I also tried using `androidComponents`  like this:

```
android {
  ...some stuff here
}

androidComponents {
  onVariants(selector().withBuildType("release")) {
    packaging.jniLibs.useLegacyPackaging = true
  }
}
```

The above will throw a build error `Cannot set reaonly property: useLegacyPackaging`.  I know it's not correct but just give it a try, and I cannot find any documentation on how to set it this way.

Any idea how I can isolate the packagingOptions to one particular build type only?  Thanks in advance.